# Having problems creating a transaction data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a python data-frame to track my stock buys, sells and profit. Right now I have a pandas data-frame with price in one column and buy-sell-hold trigger in another as well as a timestamp.

I tried creating a data-frame to track the buy sell price and profit of transaction but that didn't work out it was to hard to find the last transaction to update it. Here I am trying to create a data-frame for the transactions

Errors and current output of Tdf.tail

`Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Buy, Sell, Profit]
Index: []
single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

what df looks like

`timestamp  Price      decide
2019-08-19  3.0000       1.0
2019-08-20  2.6200       0.0
2019-08-21  2.3200       0.0
2019-08-22  2.1400       0.0
2019-08-23  1.9500      -1.0`

```
Price = [['2019-08-19',3.0000,1.0],['2019-08-20',2.6200,0.0],['2019-08-21',2.3200,0.0],['2019-08-22',2.1400,0.0],['2019-08-23',1.9500,-1.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(Price,columns = ['timestamp','Price','decide'])
df.set_index('timestamp',inplace=True)
Trades = []
Tdf = pd.DataFrame(Trades,columns = ['Buy','Sell','Profit'])

for y in df.index.values:#Buy = 1.0 , Sell = -1.0
    if df['decide'].iloc[y] == 1.0:
        Tdf.append({'Buy' : df['Price'][y]},ignore_index=True)

    if df['decide'].iloc[y] == -1.0:
        profit =  df['Price'].iloc[y] - Tdf['Buy'].iloc[-1]
        Tdf.at[-1,'Sell'] = df['Price'].iloc[y]
        Tdf.at[-1,'Profit'] = profit
```

Expected is to see Tdf to look like

      `buy   sell  profit
0     3.00  1.95 -1.05`

Comment: What did you see right now? Please post actual output also.

Comment: Just added the actual output

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had to do:

```
df = df[-30:]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
try:
    for y in df.index.values:

         if y == 0 and df['buy_sell'].iloc[y] == 1.0:
            Tdf.at[y,'Buy'] = df['Price'].iloc[y]
            buyIndex = y

         if df['buy_sell_hold'].iloc[y] == 1.0:
            Tdf.at[y,'Buy'] = df['Price'].iloc[y]
            buyIndex = y

         if y == 0 and df['buy_sell_hold'].iloc[y] == -1.0:
            print('sold something we did not buy')

         elif df['buy_sell_hold'].iloc[y] == -1.0:
            profit = df['Price'].iloc[y] - Tdf['Buy'].iloc[-1]
            Tdf.at[buyIndex,'Sell'] = df['Price'].iloc[y]
            Tdf.at[buyIndex,'Profit'] = profit
```